# Audio not starting when loading Just Audio player

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

I'm new to Flutter and followed this tutorial https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d to setup Just Audio and audioservice. I'm building my app for Android at the moment.

I'm having 3 issues:

- The main problem is that when I use context.go (from GoRouter) to move to the player screen, audio should start playing, but it doesn't, I have to manually press the Play button.
- Additionaly when I load a playlist and press Next, it also doesn't start playing automatically.
- Finally, sometimes if I leave the player for other screen and come back, I can't press the Play button.

Here are the 3 files I'm using:

Player screen:

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/screens/chapterlist_screen.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/utils/api_service.dart';
import './just_audio/notifiers/play_button_notifier.dart';
import './just_audio/notifiers/progress_notifier.dart';
import './just_audio/page_manager.dart';
import './just_audio/services/service_locator.dart';
import 'package:audio_video_progress_bar/audio_video_progress_bar.dart';

class Player extends StatefulWidget {
  const Player({super.key});

  @override
  State<Player> createState() => _PlayerState();
}

class _PlayerState extends State<Player> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getIt<PageManager>().init();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    getIt<PageManager>().dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // startPlaying();
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // const SizedBox(height: 10),

              // back button and menu button
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () => context.pop()),
                  const Text('Listening to'),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.playlist_play_outlined),
                      onPressed: () => context.push('/chapters')),
                ],
              ),

              const SizedBox(height: 25),

              // cover art, artist name, song name
              const CurrentMetadata(),

              const SizedBox(height: 30),

              const SizedBox(height: 20),

              // linear bar
              const AudioProgressBar(),

              const SizedBox(height: 30),

              // previous song, pause play, skip next song
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: const ChangeSpeedButton(),
                    ),
                    Center(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          PreviousSongButton(),
                          PlayButton(),
                          NextSongButton(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// class CurrentSongTitle extends StatelessWidget {
//   const CurrentSongTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
//   @override
//   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//     final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
//     return ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
//       valueListenable: pageManager.currentSongTitleNotifier,
//       builder: (_, title, __) {
//         return Padding(
//           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
//           child: Text(title, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
//         );
//       },
//     );
//   }
// }

class AddRemoveSongButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddRemoveSongButtons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: pageManager.add,
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: pageManager.remove,
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AudioProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const AudioProgressBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ProgressBarState>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.progressNotifier,
      builder: (_, value, __) {
        return ProgressBar(
          progress: value.current,
          buffered: value.buffered,
          total: value.total,
          onSeek: pageManager.seek,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class AudioControlButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  const AudioControlButtons({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 60,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: const [
          PreviousSongButton(),
          PlayButton(),
          NextSongButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PreviousSongButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const PreviousSongButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.isFirstSongNotifier,
      builder: (_, isFirst, __) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
          iconSize: 32,
          onPressed: (isFirst) ? null : pageManager.previous,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class PlayButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlayButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ButtonState>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.playButtonNotifier,
      builder: (_, value, __) {
        switch (value) {
          case ButtonState.loading:
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              width: 48.0,
              height: 48.0,
              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ButtonState.paused:
            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  iconSize: 48,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: pageManager.play,
                ));
          case ButtonState.playing:
            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200)),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.pause),
                  iconSize: 48,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: pageManager.pause,
                ));
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class NextSongButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const NextSongButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.isLastSongNotifier,
      builder: (_, isLast, __) {
        return IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.skip_next),
          iconSize: 32,
          onPressed: (isLast) ? null : pageManager.next,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ChangeSpeedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeSpeedButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChangeSpeedButton> createState() => _ChangeSpeedButtonState();
}

class _ChangeSpeedButtonState extends State<ChangeSpeedButton> {
  var selectedValue = 1.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton(
          icon: const Visibility(
              visible: false, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
          value: selectedValue
              .toString(), //we set a value here depending on the button pressed, and call the pagemanager method assing it the value.
          items: dropdownItems,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValue = double.parse(value.toString());
            });
            pageManager.changeSpeed(selectedValue);
          }),
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> get dropdownItems {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> menuItems = [
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "0.75", child: Text("0.75x")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1.0", child: Text("1.0x")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1.25", child: Text("1.25x")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1.5", child: Text("1.5x")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "1.75", child: Text("1.75x")),
      const DropdownMenuItem(value: "2.0", child: Text("2.0x")),
    ];
    return menuItems;
  }
}

class CurrentMetadata extends StatelessWidget {
  const CurrentMetadata({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
    return ValueListenableBuilder<MediaItem?>(
      valueListenable: pageManager.currentSongMetadataNotifier,
      builder: (context, mediaItem, child) {
        if (mediaItem == null) {
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        }
        return Column(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              child: Image.network((mediaItem.artUri ?? '').toString()),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(mediaItem.extras!['chapterName'],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .titleMedium
                              ?.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                      const SizedBox(height: 6),
                      Text(
                        mediaItem.title,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 6),
                      Text(
                        'By ${mediaItem.artist}',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleSmall,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite),
                      color: Colors.red,
                      onPressed: () {}),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );

        // Text(mediaItem.album ?? ''),
        // Text(mediaItem.displaySubtitle ?? ''),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

PageManager.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/models/getpodficlist_model.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/models/series_model.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/notifiers/chapterObject_notifier.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/utils/api_service.dart';
import 'notifiers/play_button_notifier.dart';
import 'notifiers/progress_notifier.dart';
import 'notifiers/repeat_button_notifier.dart';
import 'services/playlist_repository.dart';
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'services/service_locator.dart';

class PageManager {
  // Listeners: Updates going to the UI
  final currentSongMetadataNotifier = ValueNotifier<MediaItem?>(null);
  final playlistNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<String>>([]);
  final progressNotifier = ProgressNotifier();
  final repeatButtonNotifier = RepeatButtonNotifier();
  final isFirstSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final playButtonNotifier = PlayButtonNotifier();
  final isLastSongNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(true);
  final isShuffleModeEnabledNotifier = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  final _audioHandler = getIt<AudioHandler>();
  List<Chapter>? chapterObject = getIt<ChapterObject>().chapterObject.value;

  // Events: Calls coming from the UI
  void init() async {
    await loadPlaylist();
    _listenToChangesInPlaylist();
    _listenToPlaybackState();
    _listenToCurrentPosition();
    _listenToBufferedPosition();
    _listenToTotalDuration();
    _listenToChangesInSong();
    // _startPlaying();
  }

  Future<void> loadPlaylist() async {
    final mediaItems = seriesItems.chapterList?.map((chapter) {
          final _podficInfo = chapter.podficInfo;
          return MediaItem(
            id: _podficInfo.id.toString(),
            artUri: Uri.parse(_podficInfo.coverArt!),
            artist: seriesItems.author,
            title: seriesItems.title!,
            extras: {
              'url': _podficInfo.url,
              'chapterName':
                  "Chapter ${_podficInfo.chapterNumber}: ${_podficInfo.title}"
            },
          );
        }).toList() ??
        [];
    _audioHandler.addQueueItems(mediaItems);
  }

  // void _setInitialPlaylist() {
  //   final _seriesInfo = getIt<SeriesInfo>();
  //   final _playlist = SeriesInfo(chapterList: chapterItems);
  // }

  void play() => _audioHandler.play();
  void pause() => _audioHandler.pause();
  void seek(Duration position) => _audioHandler.seek(position);
  void previous() => _audioHandler.skipToPrevious();
  void next() => _audioHandler.skipToNext();
  void repeat() {}
  void shuffle() {}
  void add() async {
    //don't need this for now.
    final songRepository = getIt<PlaylistRepository>();
    final song = await songRepository.fetchAnotherSong();
    final mediaItem = MediaItem(
      id: song['id'] ?? '',
      album: song['album'] ?? '',
      title: song['title'] ?? '',
      extras: {'url': song['url']},
    );
    _audioHandler.addQueueItem(mediaItem);
  }

  void remove() {
    //don't need this for now.
    final lastIndex = _audioHandler.queue.value.length - 1;
    if (lastIndex < 0) return;
    _audioHandler.removeQueueItemAt(lastIndex);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _audioHandler.stop();
  }

  void _listenToChangesInPlaylist() {
    _audioHandler.queue.listen((playlist) {
      if (playlist.isEmpty) {
        playlistNotifier.value = [];
        currentSongMetadataNotifier.value = '' as MediaItem?;
      } else {
        final newList = playlist.map((item) => item.title).toList();
        playlistNotifier.value = newList;
      }
      _updateSkipButtons();
    });
  }

  void _listenToPlaybackState() {
    _audioHandler.playbackState.listen((playbackState) {
      final isPlaying = playbackState.playing;
      final processingState = playbackState.processingState;
      if (processingState == AudioProcessingState.loading ||
          processingState == AudioProcessingState.buffering) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.loading;
      } else if (!isPlaying) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.paused;
      } else if (processingState != AudioProcessingState.completed) {
        playButtonNotifier.value = ButtonState.playing;
        logger.i('Reproduciendo');
      } else {
        _audioHandler.seek(Duration.zero);
        _audioHandler.pause();
      }
    });
  }

  void _listenToCurrentPosition() {
    AudioService.position.listen((position) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: position,
        buffered: oldState.buffered,
        total: oldState.total,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToBufferedPosition() {
    _audioHandler.playbackState.listen((playbackState) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: oldState.current,
        buffered: playbackState.bufferedPosition,
        total: oldState.total,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToTotalDuration() {
    _audioHandler.mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {
      final oldState = progressNotifier.value;
      progressNotifier.value = ProgressBarState(
        current: oldState.current,
        buffered: oldState.buffered,
        total: mediaItem?.duration ?? Duration.zero,
      );
    });
  }

  void _listenToChangesInSong() {
    _audioHandler.mediaItem.listen((mediaItem) {
      currentSongMetadataNotifier.value = mediaItem;
      _updateSkipButtons();
    });
  }

  void _updateSkipButtons() {
    final mediaItem = _audioHandler.mediaItem.value;
    final playlist = _audioHandler.queue.value;
    if (playlist.length < 2 || mediaItem == null) {
      isFirstSongNotifier.value = true;
      isLastSongNotifier.value = true;
    } else {
      isFirstSongNotifier.value = playlist.first == mediaItem;
      isLastSongNotifier.value = playlist.last == mediaItem;
    }
  }

  void changeSpeed(value) {
    _audioHandler.setSpeed(value);
  }

//   void _startPlaying(){
//   _audioHandler.
// }
}


// class PlaySpeedNotifier extends ValueNotifier {
//   PlaySpeedNotifier() : super(initialSpeed);
//   static const initialSpeed = 1.0;
//   var speed = initialSpeed;

//    void changeSpeed(value) {
//     speed = value;
//     _audio
//   }

// }
```

Audiohandler.dart

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:podfic_app/utils/api_service.dart';

Future<AudioHandler> initAudioService() async {
  return await AudioService.init(
    builder: () => MyAudioHandler(),
    config: const AudioServiceConfig(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.mycompany.myapp.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'FanPods',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
      androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
    ),
  );
}

class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler {
  final _player = AudioPlayer();
  final _playlist = ConcatenatingAudioSource(children: []);

  MyAudioHandler() {
    loadEmptyPlaylist();
    _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents();
    _listenForDurationChanges();
    _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges();
  }
  Future<void> loadEmptyPlaylist() async {
    try {
      await _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);
    } catch (e) {
      logger.i('algo paso con loadEemptyplaylist');
    }
  }

  // Future<void> startPlaying() => _player.setAudioSource(_playlist);

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItems(List<MediaItem> mediaItems) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    final audioSource = mediaItems.map(_createAudioSource);
    _playlist.addAll(audioSource.toList());
    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..addAll(mediaItems);
    queue.add(newQueue);
    logger.i(newQueue);
  }

  UriAudioSource _createAudioSource(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    return AudioSource.uri(
      Uri.parse(mediaItem.extras!['url']),
      tag: mediaItem,
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> pause() => _player.pause();

  void _notifyAudioHandlerAboutPlaybackEvents() {
    _player.playbackEventStream.listen((PlaybackEvent event) {
      final playing = _player.playing;
      playbackState.add(playbackState.value.copyWith(
        controls: [
          MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
          if (playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
          MediaControl.skipToNext,
        ],
        systemActions: const {
          MediaAction.seek,
        },
        androidCompactActionIndices: const [0, 1, 3],
        processingState: const {
          ProcessingState.idle: AudioProcessingState.idle,
          ProcessingState.loading: AudioProcessingState.loading,
          ProcessingState.buffering: AudioProcessingState.buffering,
          ProcessingState.ready: AudioProcessingState.ready,
          ProcessingState.completed: AudioProcessingState.completed,
        }[_player.processingState]!,
        playing: playing,
        updatePosition: _player.position,
        bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
        speed: _player.speed,
        queueIndex: event.currentIndex,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  void _listenForDurationChanges() {
    _player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
      final index = _player.currentIndex;
      final newQueue = queue.value;
      if (index == null || newQueue.isEmpty) return;
      final oldMediaItem = newQueue[index];
      final newMediaItem = oldMediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
      newQueue[index] = newMediaItem;
      queue.add(newQueue);
      mediaItem.add(newMediaItem);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToNext() => _player.seekToNext();
  @override
  Future<void> skipToPrevious() => _player.seekToPrevious();

  void _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges() {
    _player.currentIndexStream.listen((index) {
      final playlist = queue.value;
      if (index == null || playlist.isEmpty) return;
      mediaItem.add(playlist[index]);
      logger.i(playlist);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> addQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    final audioSource = _createAudioSource(mediaItem);
    _playlist.add(audioSource);
    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..add(mediaItem);
    queue.add(newQueue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> removeQueueItemAt(int index) async {
    // manage Just Audio
    _playlist.removeAt(index);
    // notify system
    final newQueue = queue.value..removeAt(index);
    queue.add(newQueue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int index) async {
    if (index < 0 || index >= queue.value.length) return;
    if (_player.shuffleModeEnabled) {
      index = _player.shuffleIndices![index];
    }
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: index);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> stop() async {
    await _player.dispose();
    return super.stop();
  }
}
```

I tried including pageManager.play in the init section of Player and PageManager, but nothing happens. I think I need to set the audiosource as a concatenatingAudioSource, but I created a method to execute it and passed it _playlist, running it under     _listenForCurrentSongIndexChanges(), but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Realized the play method was executing before the init method finished, so simple delay worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).